# Add Firebase WebApp Source into vanilla JS or JSON without <script src>?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, bpmn, signavio

I am Modelling a BPMN Diagramm and use the Tool **Signavio Workflow**.
I have written a js Task that should save the Data in the Firebase API.

My main problem is that the generated code expect HTML-Tags but my Tool use only vanilla JS. Support said they also use JSON.

That is the generated Code of Google.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDWaO_6124QdXEDhfU2LvJ9bGYV2xB5oZM",
    authDomain: "musterbank-kundenliste.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://musterbank-kundenliste.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "musterbank-kundenliste",
    storageBucket: "mechanic-customerlist.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "138893078421"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Now I would like to add this piece of code above in my function.

```
function customerAddInAPI(customer){


}
```

I hope you guys can help. I really try to fix it but I haven´t found anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the dependency on https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js because Workflow Accelerator runs your JavaScript in a sandbox that only has a limited number of [JavaScript libraries](https://docs.signavio.com/userguide/workflow/en/integration/javascript.html#javascript-libraries) available.

Instead, you’re going to have to use the provided [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library to build and send an HTTP request to the Firebase API, which is presumably what your code sample does under the hood.